# An inequality for positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

*If $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices, then*

$0 ≤ {\rm tr}AB ≤ {\rm tr} A\,{\rm tr }B$.

I was wondering what are the sufficient and necessary conditions for the equality to hold ?

Comment: i know the inequality is true , but i want sufficient and necessary conditions for the equality to hold

Comment: For positive definite matrices, $\mbox{tr}(A,B)$ is an inner product. See here for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209950/an-inequality-on-trace-of-product-of-two-matrices

So for example $\mbox{tr}(A)\leq\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(A^2)}$ and the same for $B$ should fulfill one direction.

Comment: @AlexR.: Are you suggesting that equality holds if $A=mB$ for some constant $m$? I thought that would be the case, but that is not true:$ A=B=I$ do not realize equality. But maybe I misunderstood your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

we will give a characterisation by using the spectrum of $A$.

First we will use the inner product induced by [the Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), defined on $L(H)$ by : $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(AB^*)$ then ($A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite) Cauchy Schwarz inequality implies that :
$$
0 \leq \langle A,B\rangle^2 \leq \langle A,A\rangle \langle B,B\rangle
\\
0 \leq \operatorname{Tr}(A B)^2 \leq \operatorname{Tr}(A^2) \operatorname{Tr}(B^2) \leq \operatorname{Tr}(A)^2 \operatorname{Tr}(B)^2
$$ 
So if we have the equality it implies that we have equality in Cauchy Schwarz inequality and this implies that $B=\alpha A$ for a scalar $\alpha$.

In particular 
$$
\alpha\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)=\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B)=\alpha\operatorname{Tr}(A)^2
$$

we denote by $(a_i)_{i\leq n}$  the spectrum of $A$, so spectral theorem give :
$$
Tr(A)=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i \; \textrm{ and } \; Tr(A^2)=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i^2  
$$
so we have equality if :
$$
\left(\sum_{i\leq n}a_i\right)^2=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i^2 \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i\neq j\leq n}a_i a_j=0
$$
But $A$  is positive semidefinite so the spectrum of $A$ is non-negative then :
$$
\forall i,j\leq n \qquad i\neq j \qquad \qquad a_i a_j=0
$$
we have so 2 cases :

1.

$\exists k\leq n $ such that $a_k\neq 0$. In this case we have :
$$
\forall i\leq n \; \; i\neq k  \qquad \qquad a_i=0
$$

2.

$\forall i\leq n$ $a_i=0$. This is the trivial case and then :
$$
A= B=0
$$

So the set of solution is :
$$
\left\{(tU^*P_1 U,\alpha  U^*P_1 U), \textrm{ Where } \alpha , t\geq 0, \; U \in O_n,\;  P_1 \textrm { is a one dimensional projection }    \right\}
$$

Comment: You said $\rm{Tr}(AB)= \sum_i a_ib_i$ but  is this true even if  $A$ and $B$ do not commute ?

Comment: In this case @GiuseppeNegro it's true because $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizables (Spectral theorem), so if $A=UDU^{-1}$ and $B=VD'V^{-1}$ so $Tr(AB)=Tr(DD')$.
Witch give the equality.

Comment: I am not completely convinced by $\rm{Tr}(AB)=\rm{Tr}(DD')$. Can you show me how do you prove this identity? It is not completely trivial, because [trace is only invariant under *cyclic* permutations](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/252272/8157), not general permutations, so I do not see how you can simplify $U, U^{-1}, V, V^{-1}$. Thank you!

Comment: You have right @GiuseppeNegro the identity can't be true and then the answer also, my counterexample  is $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{array}\right)$ then $Tr(AB)=13$ but $Tr(DD')=15$

Comment: I will correct this answer now thank you

Comment: Still I don't understand something. If $A=B=I$ we should have equality, according to what you say: "if we have equality ... this implies $B=\alpha A$". However, $\rm{Tr}(I)=n$ but $\rm{Tr}(I)\cdot \rm{Tr}(I)=n^2$ and they are not equal.

Comment: no he fact that $A=B=I$ is a necessary condition only, and if you see the last characterization of solution you will see that you  example can't be a solution because $I$ is a n-dimensional solution not of dimension one !!!!

Comment: Frankly, your writing is not very clear (no offense, trying to make constructive criticism instead). One remark: if $A=UP_1U^\star$ with $P_1$ a rank one projection, then $A$ is itself a rank one projection. So your result can be rewritten more simply as follows: you claim that equality holds in $\rm{Tr}(AB)=\rm{Tr}(A)\rm{Tr}(B)$ if and only if $A=tP_1, B=\alpha A$ where $P_1$ is a rank one projection and $t\ge 0,\ \alpha \ge 0$. Did I interpret your result correctly?

Comment: excuse me for my bad english first, but your interpretation is correct and it is more pretty writed like that

Comment: No need to be sorry, it is actually clearer than I said, it was me who was reading carelessly. Now I think that this is correct and also it is a very good solution. +1