# Hilbert-Schmidt distance triangle inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I want to prove the triangle inequality for the Hilbert-Schmidt distance between density matrices. Let $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3$ be density matrices (in particular these have trace equal to 1 and are Hermitian) and $D_{HS}(\rho_1,\rho_2) = \mathrm{Tr}((\rho_1 - \rho_2)^2)$ the Hilbert-Schmidt distance (ignoring $1/2$ for now). I want to prove that $D_{HS}(\rho_1,\rho_3)+D_{HS}(\rho_3,\rho_2) \geq D_{HS}(\rho_1,\rho_2)$. Writing this out I have that one needs $2\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_3^2) -2\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1 \rho_3) - 2\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_2 \rho_3) \geq -2\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1 \rho_2)$. However it is not so clear for me why this holds? I think maybe due to $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1 \rho_3)\leq 1$ etc. but how do you prove this?

Comment: It might be simpler *not* to use self-adjointness of density matrices and first price that Hilbert-Schmidt inner product $\operatorname{tr}(A^*B)$ is indeed an inner product, and use the standard theory of inner products.

Comment: @lisyarus Yes that is useful. I also found this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209950/an-inequality-on-trace-of-product-of-two-matrices in which it is proven that $\mathrm{Tr}(AB) \leq 1$ for $\mathrm{Tr}(A) = \mathrm{Tr}(B) = 1$ with $A,B$ positive definite matrices.

Comment: Once you have proven that it is indeed a scalar product you are done. However, proofing that it is a scalar product is pretty straight forward. So there is no need to show the triangular inequality "by hand" since this follows in general from the Cauchy Schwartz inequality for scalar products. Does this help? Or do you explicitly want to show the triangular inequality by hand?

Comment: @hal4math I tried to prove it explicitly and this can be done using the link I stated above. But indeed it also directly follows from Cauchy Schwartz inequality for inner products. The problem is now solved.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Modulu the fact that in general your density matrices will be defined on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces. But the result from the link above extends also to that case.